# Can not save changes after an edit

Tags: updates

I have just started using wordpress to create a website but in some pages of the website I have issues when saving my edits.

For example, if I try to modify the text in the page and click on "preview" all the modifications that I applied are taken into account in the preview page. However, if I then click on "update" none of the edits are saved.

This happens only for some pages of the website.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/rebusted/ After activating if site works fine then it can be cache issue. Purge cache on your browser or server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to empty the cache using rebusted or other plugins while also deleting the cache on my browser. However, it does not seem to solve the problem.